# No "Enable EVL Core" in menufonfig

Tags: xenomai, real-time-systems

I was building Xenomai 4 following the [tutorial](https://evlproject.org/core/build-steps/), yet after downloading the [linux-evl v5.15.y-evl-rebase](https://source.denx.de/Xenomai/xenomai4/linux-evl), and running the command

> make menuconfig

There is no **Enable the EVL Core** option in the **General Setup**
menu as the [tutorial](https://evlproject.org/core/build-steps/) suggests in the **Build the Core** chapter. And there are also no **CONFIG_EVL_XXX** options in *.configure* file.

What have I did wrong?

My Linux is Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS with kernel Linux 5.15.0-47 X86/64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is no longer in general setup. Please check in the processor types and feature.